# Passing array of String as static param in Struts 2

Tags: arrays, string, parameters, static, struts2

I wanted to declare an action in such a way that I could pass `String` array of static parameter. I tried the below code:

```
<action name="saveRecord" class="saveRecordAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">tiles:saveRecordSuccess</result>
        <param name="names">name1</param>
        <param name="names">name2</param>
        <param name="names">name3</param>
    </action>
```

I have a setter in my action class:

```
public void setNames(String[] name){
    mNames = name;
}
```

But I am only receiving one name which is the last one, `"name3"`

Is what I wanted possible? if yes, what is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struts static param works like MAP. name been the KEY and value as VALUE.
You can achieve your requirement by sending the values as comma separated and you can split it  so that you can have your array there.

```
<param name="names">name1,name2,name3</param>
```

[For more info on Static Parameters](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/how-do-we-access-static-parameters-from-an-action.html)

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment, because I thought this will split into array automatically.  I initially thought of this solution, but if there's a legitimate solution out there, it would be better. I still wait for someone that might know the answer, if not, i'll fallback to this.

Comment: @Macchiato How about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK static parameters are converted to String, that why various interceptors (e.g. `FileUploadInterceptor`) use static method `commaDelimitedStringToSet` of `TextParseUtil` to convert `String` to `Set<String>`. You can call this method inside setter for your property.

```
public void setNames(String name) {
    mNames = TextParseUtil.commaDelimitedStringToSet(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <action name="saveRecord" class="saveRecordAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">tiles:saveRecordSuccess</result>
            <param name="names" value="new java.lang.String[]{'name1', 'name2', 'name3'}"></param>

</action>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this code didn't work.  It gave me an array with a single value "new java.lang.String[]{'name1', 'name2', 'name3'}"  it didn't split to an array of 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

The static parameters processed by the [`staticParams` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/static-parameters-interceptor.html) via the action config where the parameters are defined as `Map<String,String>`.

For proper use of static parameters in the action config you should include reference to the interceptor `staticParams` or use the `defaultStack`.

```
<interceptor-ref name="staticParams">
      <param name="parse">true</param>
      <param name="overwrite">false</param>    
</interceptor-ref>
```

You have also include `setParams(Map<String,String> params)` in the action to the interceptor set the values of the params. Use different keys `name1, name2, name3` in your case to retrieve the values of the map. You can also try `overwrite` property (not documented) for the static params to not overwrite the value with the same key.

You can see the example of using static parameters in action config: [Configure static parameter for Action class](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-configure-static-parameter-for-action-class/)

Answer (score 0):

try names[] instead names

```
 <action name="saveRecord" class="saveRecordAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">tiles:saveRecordSuccess</result>
            <param name="names[]">name1</param>
            <param name="names[]">name2</param>
            <param name="names[]">name3</param>
        </action>
```